# pod install getting stuck grpc-core 1.49.1 on terminal macOs

Tags: terminal, cocoapods, podfile, pod-install

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing ActionSheetPicker-3.0 (2.7.3)
Installing BoringSSL-GRPC (0.0.24)
Installing Cosmos (23.0.0)
Installing EFCountingLabel (5.1.5)
Installing Firebase (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseABTesting (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseAppCheckInterop (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCore (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreExtension (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCoreInternal (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseCrashlytics (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestore (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseFirestoreInternal (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseInAppMessaging (10.22.0-beta)
Installing FirebaseInstallations (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseMessaging (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseSessions (10.22.0)
Installing FirebaseSharedSwift (10.22.0)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (10.14.0)
Installing GoogleAppMeasurement (10.22.0)
Installing GoogleDataTransport (9.4.1)
Installing GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (2.1.0)
Installing GoogleUtilities (7.13.0)
Installing IQKeyboardManagerSwift (6.5.16)
Installing Libuv-gRPC (0.0.10)
Installing PromisesObjC (2.4.0)
Installing PromisesSwift (2.4.0)
Installing ReachabilitySwift (5.0.0)
Installing SVProgressHUD (2.2.5)
Installing SwiftLocation (4.2.0)
Installing abseil (1.20220623.0)
Installing gRPC-C++ (1.49.1)
Installing gRPC-Core (1.49.1)

[!] Error installing gRPC-Core
[!] /usr/bin/git -C /var/folders/t7/y12bwqj52nn4crp4lw_4yv4c0000gn/T/d20240316-1431-hk65wf submodule update --init --recursive